# How to render DOM changes inside intensive task?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, dom

I am running `O(N^4)` task. Not talking about the details - I want to update DOM inside the first loop. The *pseudocode* is this:

```
for (var a = 0; a < lim; a++) {
  updateDOM();

  for (var a = 0; a < lim; a++) {
    for (var a = 0; a < lim; a++) {
      for (var a = 0; a < lim; a++) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now the problem is that `updateDOM()` is called but never renders the apropriate DOM changes.  All the calculations take up a few seconds.

**My solutions:**

- use web workers
- settimeout

I have not tested any of them but doubt they would fix the issue. I would appreciate any help in this case.

Comment: ummm. Why are you using the same variable for all of the loops? Won't that caused undesired behavior or infinit loops?

Comment: Thats just a demo pseudocode. Thats why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either should fix the issue. The problem is that nothing else happens in the browser as long as the script is running. Until your function ends, the browser won't show any updates at all.

Using `setTimeout` you would just exit your function to let the browser show the update, then let the timeout start you function again so that you can continue where you left off.

Example:

```
function loop(a) {
    for (var b = 0; b < 10000000; b++) {}
    $('div').text(a);
    a++;
    if (a < 1000) {
        window.setTimeout(function(){ loop(a); }, 0);
    }
}

loop(0);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/47FMM/

Comment: Thanks. Will implement possibly this method

Comment: Also could you elaborate a bit more? Does browser suspend DOM rendering while in a loop or what? Or does it have a threshold on cpu or something?

Comment: @lukas.pukenis: Javascript is strictly single threaded (with the exception of background workers). As long as a script is running, nothing happens in the browser interface. No events are handled, the page is not updated, even animated gifs aren't animated.

Comment: Thanks! Totally forgot about event model of js!